# WPF TextBox MaxLength Warning

Tags: wpf, textbox, warnings, alert, maxlength

Is there anyway to fire a visible and audible warning when a user attempts to type more characters than allowed with the TextBox.MaxLength property?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ValidationRule on the Binding. If the validation will fail, the default ErrorTemplate will be used for the TextBox, otherwise you can also customize it...

example of the ValidatonRule:

```
class MaxLengthValidator : ValidationRule
{
    public MaxLengthValidator()
    {

    }

    public int MaxLength
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (value.ToString().Length <= MaxLength)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
        else
        {
            //Here you can also play the sound...
            return new ValidationResult(false, "too long");
        }

    }
}
```

and how to add it to the binding:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="target" />
<TextBox  Height="23" Name="textBox1" Width="120">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Mode="OneWayToSource" ElementName="target" Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:MaxLengthValidator MaxLength="10" />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: while this solution does not actually look at the TextBox.MaxLength property (which we use and is generated dynamically at runtime) it does prompt the question, does the validationRule failure trigger audible feedback?

Comment: is there a way to use this with the textbox's MaxLength property?

Comment: normally doesnt trigger a sound, but you can see in the code a lilne "//Here you can also play the sound... ". there you can play any sound you want.

Comment: in your implementation it will not work exactly like that if you will hold the maxLength property on the textbox. With the maxLength the text will never get longer than the maxlength, so the validationrule will always validate. but if you can remove the MaxLength from the textbox and handle it with the validator, you have the same possibilities, with more customization options